# How to change Content Type for Request Header in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

I have this legacy code in Symfony 2. I don't know much about Symfony and I have this requests that have JSON formatted content, but the header has content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8. I need to change this to application/json, but I can't find where Symfony dispatches the request to the server.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/json');
$response->send();
```

Also, it is worth referring to Symfony's documentation [Symfony HttpFoundation Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html)